# Cannot access google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to learn Google's gdata Python API, and trying to get initial access to a test spreadsheet in my drive. heres the code I am using as a test:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gdata.spreadsheets.client

# 認証に必要な情報
client_email = "59508263769-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" # 手順2で発行されたメールアドレス
with open("C:\Users\User2\Downloads\My Project-e7c4abb055f3.p12") as f: private_key = f.read() # 手順2で発行された秘密鍵

# 認証情報の作成
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(client_email, private_key,
    scope=scope)

# スプレッドシート用クライアントの準備
client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()

# OAuth2.0での認証設定
auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
auth_token.authorize(client)

# ---- これでライブラリを利用してスプレッドシートにアクセスできる ---- #

# ワークシートの取得
sheets = client.get_worksheets("1RRajoMlKP2plSnE12dt_BqVbk9TihCpDpumvhF-y7vM") # スプレッドシートIDを指定
for sheet in sheets.entry:
    print sheet.get_worksheet_id(), sheet.title
```

I'm basing it off of this tutorial http://qiita.com/koyopro/items/d8d56f69f863f07e9378 (sorry its all in Japanese).

The method this guy is proposing is using something called a p12 as a key(?) to gain access to things in your Google Apps when creating OAuth2 credentials. Then sharing your spread sheet to an @developer email address generated.

I run this code and it's fine, until it hits

```
sheets = client.get_worksheets("1RRajoMlKP2plSnE12dt_BqVbk9TihCpDpumvhF-y7vM") # スプレッドシートIDを指定
```

And this gives me the following errors:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========= RESTART: C:\Users\User2\Documents\googlePythonTest04_01.py =========

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User2\Documents\googlePythonTest04_01.py", line 24, in <module>
    sheets = client.get_worksheets("1RRajoMlKP2plSnE12dt_BqVbk9TihCpDpumvhF-y7vM") # ã‚¹ãƒ—ãƒ¬ãƒƒãƒ‰ã‚·ãƒ¼ãƒˆIDã‚’æŒ‡å®š
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\spreadsheets\client.py", line 108, in get_worksheets
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 640, in get_feed
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 267, in request
    uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token, http_request=http_request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\atom\client.py", line 122, in request
    return self.http_client.request(http_request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\gauth.py", line 1332, in new_request
    refresh_response = self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\gauth.py", line 1473, in _refresh
    self.credentials._refresh(httplib2.Http().request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 873, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 900, in _do_refresh_request
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 1611, in _generate_refresh_request_body
    assertion = self._generate_assertion()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 396, in _generate_assertion
    key_id=self._private_key_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 97, in make_signed_jwt
    signature = signer.sign(signing_input)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sign'
>>>
```

According to this tutorial, the last print command should return

```
od6 <ns0:title xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">&#12471;&#12540;&#12488;1</ns0:title>0
```

But its giving me this string/sign error.

Am I doing something wrong? Or did the API change on this get_worksheets command? I know a lot of things might have changed since this tutorial was written since I had to change the "import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials" to "import ServiceAccountCredentials" because apparently SignedJwtAssertionCredentials no longer exists (according to this thread: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/401)

I know I could be using this other much simpler "gspread" API, but my understanding is that you can't actually edit a spreadsheet with it so I am just going with gdata.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Stop using the gdata API.   Use Google Sheets v4 you will have much better luck https://developers.google.com/sheets/    I will be willing to bet v3 will be depreciated soon which will mean in a year you will have to migrate anyway.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought this Google Sheets v4 is part of gdata? How do i then use v4?

Comment: V3 is gdata v4 is a discovery service api.

Answer (score 1):

Google has rolled out v4 api for spreadsheets with a basket full of options. since i found it hard to use the google client library, I wrote an python library ([pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets)) for google spread sheets on top of google python client. The library is in development phase so if you find any feature missing feel free to send a pull request or just create an issue. If you need a more stable library and doesn't require new api checkout [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) and yeah, you can edit a spreadsheet with gspread.

The usage is as simple as

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize()

# Open a worksheet from spreadsheet with one shot
wks = gc.open('my new ssheet').sheet1

wks.update_acell('B2', "it's down there somewhere, let me take another look.")

# Fetch a cell range
cell_list = wks.range('A1:B7')
```